# Difference between SELECT function() AS column and SELECT function() column

Tags: postgresql

What is the difference between for instance:

```
SELECT coalesce(a,b,c) AS d from table;
```

and

```
SELECT coalesce(a,b,c) d from table;
```

both returns the same result. Does it means that `AS` is optional?

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name when you dont know what to look for, searching for the keyword AS in hundreds of pages of doc is helpless

Comment: When looking at a manual, you shouldn't be searching for keywords. The way I find things like that is to check the table of contents and then think which part might cover my question. As this is about a `SELECT` statement, Chapter 7 "Queries" looks like a good starting point. Then I open that, and I see a chapter "Select List Items" - and there you go. Reading a manual is not the same as using a search engine. Finding your way around manuals is just as important as learning the actual technology

Comment: yes you are right, I'll search deeper next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is optional. From the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS): "*The AS keyword is optional, but only if the new column name does not match any PostgreSQL keyword*"

Comment: Thank you is this valid for any version?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I would guess it is, although I haven't read the documentation for older versions.